# How to do a POST request with headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Right now, I'm trying to do a post request:

https://aleapisoap.azure-api.net/httpbin/listSearchFields

And I need a body which is this:

```
{
  "listSearchFields": {
    "email": "sample"
  }
}
```

I tried this in postman and works but with this code in JavaScript doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'https://aleapisoap.azure-api.net/httpbin/listSearchFields',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type':'application/json',
                        'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
                        'Ocp-Apim-Trace':'true',
                        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'19f2a7fd474840bfb5fc729cd97b7335'
                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    data: '{"listSearchFields":{"email":"sample"}}',
                    success: function(data){
                    console.log('succes: '+data);
                    }
                });
```

This is the error:

net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Resource Not Found)

Comment: Even with postman it is returning `Unexpected ','` and with `AJAX` also same

Comment: Try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-api-inspector) and enable the trace please

Comment: yeah but with postman it retrieves response, with javascript it doesn't

Comment: If doesn't work from your app, because of the CORS policy. You specified `jsonp` type, so usually you should have an additional key in your $.ajax configuration object, that holds the function that has to be called in order for this to work. Do you have some kind of documentation?

Comment: No, I don't  I just created an api management on azure, it gives me a request url and now I am consume it

Answer (score 0):

The headers in your $.ajax() call look correct to me. I think the "listSearchFields" endpoint doesn't exist at https://aleapisoap.azure-api.net/httpbin/ like you're expecting. Check your spelling first - if you're spelling "listSearchFields" correctly, you'll have to dive deeper to figure out why it's not being found.

Comment: If you run it from postman, it does indeed return data. I suspect it rejects GET requests with a 404.

Comment: The $.ajax() call is a POST, though.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> dataType: 'jsonp',
> ```

JSONP requests are incompatible with setting custom request headers or making POST requests. They work by injecting a `<script>` element with a `src` attribute (which makes a GET request).

If you need to make a POST request, don't use that `dataType`. You probably want `'json'`.

JSONP is a hack that was used to work around the [Same Origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) before CORS was available. You might have to take other steps to ensure the endpoint is available to your origin.